# Using Transforms in PyTorch

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

I have a tensor X of Cat/No cat images in PyTorch and wanted to apply Transformations on it. Is there any way to so without data loaders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [functional transforms](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#functional-transforms). 
Example of adding padding:

```
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms

pil_image = Image.open("path/to/image.jpg")
img_with_padding = transforms.functional.pad(pil_image,(10,10)) # Add 10px pad
tensor_img = transforms.functional.to_tensor(img_with_padding)
```

See full example here: https://github.com/Gan4x4/CV-HSE2019/blob/master/helloworld/Dataset_and_Dataloader.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Assuming you're talking about `torchvision.transforms`, they do not depend on DataLoaders. For instance:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from torchvision import transforms

torch.manual_seed(2020)

# lets say this is your image (you said it is a tensor, not a PIL Image)
x = (torch.rand((2,3)) * 255.).to(torch.uint8)

# this is your transformation... they need it to be a PIL Image :(
t = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=1.0), # 100% just to make sure we see it being applied
    transforms.Lambda(lambda x: torch.tensor(np.array(x)))
])

# this is how you can apply the transformation
transformed_x = t(x)

print(x)
# tensor([[124,  26, 150],
#         [ 29, 126,  72]], dtype=torch.uint8)

print(transformed_x)
# tensor([[150,  26, 124],
#         [ 72, 126,  29]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

If you have custom transformations that work on tensor, you can remove the whole "tensor -> PIL -> tensor" thing.